# Getting `Cannot find module 'jsdom-quokka-plugin'` in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, quokka.js

I am getting following error, when running **quokka** plugin in WebStorm. How to resolve it?

```
Quokka #1 (node: v6.9.5, plugins: jsdom-quokka-plugin)

Cannot find module 'jsdom-quokka-plugin'`
```

I can reinstall WebStorm but it does not help.

Comment: are you using [quokka](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9667-quokka) plugin? Please report the issue to plugin vendor: https://github.com/wallabyjs/quokka/issues. Looks like a configuration issue

Answer (score 3):

Solved it by removing "jsdom-quokka-plugin" plugin entry at `~/.quokka/config.json`

Answer (score 1):

You may either remove the jsdom-quokka-plugin plugin from your [Quokka config file](https://quokkajs.com/docs/configuration.html#global-config-file), or install it (by running `npm i`) in your project, or in the Quokka config folder.